# Dialogflow agent entities to be contacted through REST APIs

Tags: rest, dialogflow-es

I am developing an agent, and have an entity within the agent.
now what i need is to add some new details to the entity, but not by opening dialogflow.
I want to make a REST API to add it for me.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the API to either [create](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/create) or [patch](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/patch) entities.

Comment: to be very honest, i myself don't know much. I am just trying and learning stuff..

Comment: Trying and learning stuff is great! StackOverflow is better when you've tried something and it doesn't work as you expect and you can't figure out why, or if you can provide detailed questions where you've broken down the problem. Sometimes you realize, when you've broken it down this way, that you can figure out the problem on your own. But we're here to help as best we can.

Comment: Sure Prisoner, Thanks for the input and will pay attention to that from now. Thank You..!

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck! If an answer has helped you, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/create-manage-entities), it doesn't look like this is possible via HTTP requests.

You could try `automated expansion`:

> Automated expansion of developer entities allows an agent to recognize
>   values that have not been explicitly listed in the entity.
>
> If a user's request includes an item that isn't listed in the entity,
>   automatic expansion recognizes the undefined item as a parameter in
>   the entity. The agent sees the user's request is similar to the
>   examples provided, so it can derive what the item is in the request.
>
> For example, consider a shopping list with items to buy:

[image: automated expansion for Dialogflow entities]

> If a user says "I need to buy some vegetables", "vegetables" will be
>   picked up as a value, even though it's not included in the @item
>   entity. With automated expansion enabled, the agent sees the user's
>   query is similar to the training phrases provided in the intent and
>   can pick out what should be extracted as a new value.
>
> The closer the user's input is to the examples provided in the
>   training phrases section, the better the results the automated
>   expansion feature provides. This is another reason to provide as many
>   examples as possible.

Comment: i tried this, but it mostly fails, but i am gonna try that again. Thank you..!